# How to make the code compile and preserve functionality?

Tags: java

i am new into java.. How do i fix this, so it will compile and preserve the functionality without changing dingo method. So this code should check if Pingo is a valid class.

```
class Pingo<T> {
    public void dingo(T t ) {
        System.out.println(t.bingoString( )) ;
    }
}
```

Comment: You would start by reading a tutorial on Java Generics, like: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/why.html

Comment: It is pretty simple: unless you further specify that T generic type, it boils down to java.lang.Object. Object does not have a method `bingoString()`. That is all there is to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The T is a generic type. In your case it's the Object class which doesn't have a method called bingoString. You need to create a class which has this method for the template. E.g.:

```
// still your class
class Pingo<T extends Blub> {
    public void dingo(T t) {
        System.out.println(t.bingoString());
    }
}
// a class which provides the signature
class Blub {
    public String bingoString() {
        return "test";
    }
}
```